# Fast Reading File With Indices

Tags: c#, linq, readlines

I am trying to read a huge file. Previously i used `File.ReadLines` which will not read the entire data into memory. Now i need to access the previous & next line while iterating. I tried reading the entire file but got an `OutofMemoryException`.

I then started searching for a solution and found that i can use Linq. I tried using the following:

```
    var inputLines = File.ReadLines(filePath);
    int count = inputLines.Count();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        string line = inputLines.Skip(i).Take(1).First();
    }
```

This is very slow. I think each time it Skip and then Take, it keeps reading all the lines over and over again at each loop.

Is there a better way to do it ? The only solution i could think of right now is to split my file into smaller chunks so i can read it but i can't really believe that there is no workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you iterating through all the lines in the file and want to compare three lines (previous, current, and next) each time you look at a new line?

If so, how about just keep track of the last two lines as you iterate through all of them:

```cs
    string previousLine = null,
           currentLine = null;

    foreach (string nextLine in File.ReadLines(filePath))
    {
        if (previousLine == null)
        {
            // Do something special for the first two lines?
        }
        else
        {
            // You're past the first two lines and now have previous,
            // current, and next lines to compare.
        }

        // Save for next iteration
        previousLine = currentLine;
        currentLine = nextLine;
    }
```

Comment: I need to read the previousLine & nextLine of the current line i am reading. I thought of your way but it will be kinda complex for. There will be a lot of if statements while i parse the data.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you wanted the next line also. I updated my proposed solution. I believe you'll only need the single if statement right?